# Longitude return null when retrieving from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Firebase locationRef = mRootRef.child("location");
    locationRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map <Double, Double>map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            Double latitude = map.get("latitude");
            Double longitude = map.get("longitude");

            Log.v("Lat_Long", String.valueOf(latitude) + " "+ String.valueOf(longitude));

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Below is the data structure in firebase:

[image]

From the logcat, latitude returns fine. I just don't get why the longitude returns as null. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you're reading from the wrong location (a common mistake). But definitely give this code a try:

```
Firebase locationRef = mRootRef.child("location");
locationRef.addValueEventListener(new com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        Double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

        Log.v("Lat_Long", String.valueOf(latitude) + " "+ String.valueOf(longitude));

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        throw firebaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Changes:

1. uses `DataSnapshot.child()` instead of converting to a `Map`
2. doesn't ignore errors

As said: not sure if this catches the problem, but it's definitely more idiomatic code for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi, it is still null. Don't understand why. The logcat shows ths: 09-26 08:57:41.119 19943-19943/com.example.jingwen.firebaselogin V/Lat_Long: 5.2913 null

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem in getting the Double value , so try this :

```
Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(map.get("latitude"));
Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(map.get("longitude"));
```

Comment: It returns error. Stated as "parseDouble (java.lang.String) in Double cannot be applied to (java.lang.Double)"

Comment: Could you please write the result of this 
Log.v("Lat_Long", String.valueOf(latitude) + " "+ String.valueOf(longitude));

Comment: The logcat shows ths: 09-26 08:55:45.316 19943-19943/com.example.jingwen.firebaselogin V/Lat_Long: 5.2913 null

Comment: Could you please paste the source code of your  Map class ?

Comment: I solved the issue by setting the variable in Firebase. From latitude to '0' and longitude to '1'.  Thank you very much sir for your help.